# Splitting String Methodically

Tags: python

Given the string below, how can I best split the long string with times such as that I receive Productivity & Costs (Preliminary)(08:30) & then  separately Consumer Credit Panel(11:00)

The following code depicts my long string:

```
['Productivity & Costs (Preliminary)(08:30)Consumer Credit Panel(11:00) ']
```

Comment: What is the splitting criterion? You're not splitting on every parentheses, since you didn't split on the open paren before `08`. Just one example string and a vague "I want these two outputs" is not enough for us to infer a pattern. Describe, in words, what algorithm you, as a human reader, would use to split this string. And then implement that in code

Answer (score 0):

The question is kind of confusing, but from what I can tell, you want to split your string into `[‘Productivity & Costs (Preliminary)(08:30)’,’Consumer Credit Panel(11:00)’]`

Assuming that you always want to split on ‘Consumer’, this should work:

```py
import re
str_to_split = ‘Productivity & Costs (Preliminary)(08:30)Consumer Credit Panel(11:00)’
# str_arr is the list of the 2 strings
str_arr = re.split(‘(?=Consumer)’, str_to_split)
```

Again, I’m not sure what your end goal is here, so this answer is likely incomplete.

Answer (score -1):

```
data = 'Productivity & Costs (Preliminary)(08:30)Consumer Credit Panel(11:00) '
x = re.findall(r'.*?\(\d\d:\d\d\)', data)
```

- `.*?` search for anything non-greedy
- `\(\d\d:\d\d\)` find time, sort of `(01:23)`
- `re.findall(...)` find all phrases like `whatever the message (01:23)`